# How to prevent form submit if user delete the field using inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent form submission if the user purposely deletes the field using inspect element. Currently I'm using custom validation using jquery.

Comment: If a user is smart enough to delete a field using DevTools, they can also submit the form, there's nothing you can do to prevent it. Validate the form on the server, and count the fields, and reject if all the fields are not send.

Comment: The Client can always be altered. Do tests to prevent submission, like testing for the correct values, but don't go that far with it. Real prevention happens on the Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get every field of the form by ID or any method and match with the form before send. Here is the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

But the correct way will be checking form data on the Back End. Validate form in FrontEnd must be only for check data type or trivial things.
The reality is that if the user is so smart to change web document, checking form HTML is useless.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe way to handle validation is to do it in the backend too not just in the frontend, as mentioned in the comments users still can trick your frontend code to submit the form, anyway here is a way to prevent the form submittion if an element was removed, I'm using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) to observe any changes on the child element of `<ul>` tag and using a flag to prevent form from submitting, note that there is a timer run after 4 second to remove element, you can submit the form before the 4 second window:

```js
var submitFlag = 1;

function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    switch(mutation.type) {
      case 'childList':
        if(mutation.removedNodes.length) { // ADD YOUR CONDITION HERE FOR FORM ELEMENTS
          submitFlag = 0;  
        }

        break;
    }
  });
}



var targetNode = document.querySelector("#someElement");
var observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true //Omit or set to false to observe only changes to the parent node.
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);

setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('el2').remove();
}, 4000);

function submitHandler(event) {
  if(submitFlag === 1) {
    console.log('submitted');
  }
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("can't submit");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="someElement">
  <ul>
    <li> element 1 </li>
    <li id="el2"> element 2 </li>
    <li> element 3 </li>
    <li> element 4 </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form onsubmit="submitHandler(event)">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code, and a user can simply remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the form tag, or rewrite the global function ...

Comment: yes, that's right, and this what I said in my answer above, developers should also implement backend validation for all endpoints they have in their codebase.